# Is Fractional Calculus an important research topic "in pure mathematics" today?

Tags: analysis, soft-question, fractional-calculus, research

Being a potential graduate student, I would like to know if fractional calculus is an actively developing research topic **in the area of pure mathematics** today.

Comment: It is better to have a full understanding of calculus rather than a fractional understanding of calculus.

Comment: I doubt that...